# stretching images in cell.background view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to make cell background stretch properly when in landscape mode.  I' written this code:

```
UIImage* cellBackGroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_listing_default.png"];

cellBackGroundImage = [cellBackGroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:290 topCapHeight:76];

deselectedBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellBackGroundImage] ;

[deselectedBackground setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill]; 

cell.backgroundView = deselectedBackground;
```

The image size is 580x152. The cell size is 280x76.

But when I turn my device into landscape the rounded corners of my image is scaled but they shouldn't.

Portrait appearance: [Portrait appearance http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/6/6/upload/456703d5.png](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/6/6/upload/456703d5.png)

Landscape appearance: [Landscape appearance http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/d/0/upload/a99fb3a8.png](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/d/0/upload/a99fb3a8.png)

The image itself: [The image itself http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/6/6/upload/e1895d8e.png](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/6/6/upload/e1895d8e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what had caused my problems. Actually it is the image itself. Stretching and auto-sizing works properly when image is smaller than the result, but if it should be wider and  lower (as it was in my case) it doesn't. 
  So to solve my issue I, just, had to use smaller image.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your cap values are wrong?

```
cellBackGroundImage = [cellBackGroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:290 topCapHeight:76];
```

Why are they so big? Do your rounded corners have such a big radius? If they are only like 10px, than use `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 10 topCapHeight: 10`. These values define, which portion of the image won't be scaled.

Could you perhaps show us your image?

Comment: I had tried cellBackGroundImage = [cellBackGroundImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10]; but it didn't help

Comment: so these are you retina images i guess? so in retina the edges are about 30px. So you should be fine with a capvalue of 15 points. (if these are no retina images, use 30 points). If it still doesn't work, please show us more of your code. And go ahead and accept some answers to you questions!

Comment: There is no actual is mistake in the given code, please show more of your viewcontroller code. like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and perhaps `shouldRotateToInterfaceRotation`.. and tell us your viewStructure. How is the table resized on rotation? You're using autoresizingFlags, don't you?